# Make ball Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script where i can move a ball, horizontal and vertical. I managed to get that working.

But now I want to make my ball "jump". I ended with script below, but now my ball just get launched like a rocket xD

Can anyone help me out

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    public GUIText countText;
    public GUIText winText;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = " "; 
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);
        Vector3 jump = new Vector3 (0, jumpSpeed, 0);

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (jump * jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PickUp") {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count +1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 10) 
        {
            winText.text = "YOU WIN!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to remember reading that for jumping you are better off just setting the velocity rather than trying to impart an impulse to the character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping does not work with adding a continuous force on an object. You will have to apply a single impulse to the object once when the jump button is first pressed. This impulse will also not include a time factor, because it is applied only once. So you would get something like this:

```
bool jumping;

if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && !this.jumping);
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (jumpForce * new Vector3(0,1,0));
    this.jumping = true;
}
```

Also note that in your example you are multiplying the upward unit vector by the jumpspeed twice. Once in the `jump` vector initialization and then once in the `AddForce` method.

Of course, you will also have to make sure that gravity applies to pull the object back down (and if the object hits the ground, reset the jump bool.

In general, depending on what kind of game you are making, it is easier to just set the velocity of the object yourself and don't work with the Unity physics engine to do some simple moving around.

Comment: Thank you, this was very usefull. I decided to go with the velocity part.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code in the function `FixedUpdate`:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"));
```

in that way you are applying a force on your object at every frame because the semicolon is excluding the row below from the condition. By removing the semicolon you will have a correct if implementation in case of a jump, as long as on your RigidBody component UseGravity is enabled.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (jump * jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, it was a great help. I now have a jumping character. One who can only jump when grounded.

```
public bool IsGrounded;

    void OnCollisionStay (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    IsGrounded = true;  
}

void OnCollisionExit (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    IsGrounded = false;
}


if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && IsGrounded)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
    }
```